# Modx revo regClientStartupScript 404

Tags: javascript, php, modx, modx-revolution, modx-snippets

I create a snippet called `myscripttest`:

```
<?php
$modx->regClientStartupScript('assets/templates/js/myscript.js');
```

put myscript.js into `assets/templates/js`, call `[myscripttest]` from my document. Result: it returns 404 for `assets/templates/js/myscript.js`. Same after I clear cash.

But if I include default scripts via this snippet, everything works.

**EDITED:**

Nothing changes when I add a slash:

```
<?php
$modx->regClientStartupScript('/assets/templates/js/myscript.js');
```

Comment: What happens if you make the path absolute? Eg add `[[++site_url]]` to the start of it?

Answer (score 0):

Please look in the browser console, which url path is used to access the file. Is the file located there? If yes: Is the script file readable by apache/nginx? If not to assign 644 as file permissions.

Comment: The file is uploaded to the url via ftp and is there, but I can't access it in my browser. Yet I can access via browser other js files that have been in the same directory before. The script is readable, tried changing permissions up to 777.

Answer (score 0):

Load the full url to the script in your browsers address bar. If it show up use your configs' assets path:

`$modx->regClientStartupScript(MODX_ASSETS_PATH . 'templates/js/myscript.js');`